# Installation issue fatal error: QtOpenGL/qgl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, qt

What madness is this? Tried installing icub simulator from sources and when compilation reaches 54% then this madness happens.

```
/icub-main/src/tools/iCubGui/src/animationview.cpp:35:0:
/home/zzz/Softwares/icub-main/src/tools/iCubGui/src/animationview.h:21:26: fatal error: QtOpenGL/qgl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <QtOpenGL/qgl.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/tools/iCubGui/src/CMakeFiles/iCubGui.dir/animationview.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/tools/iCubGui/src/CMakeFiles/iCubGui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Its also located at:

```
# locate qgl.h
/usr/include/qt4/Qt/qgl.h
/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h
```

1st Query: library is installed why is the script asking for it again?
2nd : How to add this library to the CMakeLists.txt to avoid future errors.

I tried include_directories("QtOpenGL/qgl.h"). Problem still persists.

Thanks